# Disallow voting on comments if a post is locked

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, locked

Disallow voting on comments if a post is locked.   Why show the buttons for voting, etc. if the post is locked and no changes can happen.

Comment: The title of this post does not correctly communicate your intention

Answer (score 4):

Because voting on comments really serves no purpose other than to highlight something you agree with and there is no reputation gained or lost from it. All you get now is the possibility at a pundit badge, but that is only recently introduced.