# Trying to upvote a locked post comment looks buggy

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, up-votes

When you try to upvote a *locked* post, you end up with a message saying "locked posts can't be voted on":

[image: Fail to upvote a locked post]

Now when you try to upvote a comment related to a locked post - upvote that you also can't do - there is no message, but only the upvote arrow drawn and the upvote count of the comment erased:

[image: Fail to upvote a locked comment]

I get that there is no "error" message when you fail to upvote a comment, but is it normal that the upvote count is not drawn again after some sec? The only way to see the upvote count is then to refresh the page.

(Not that this is a major bug, but this is *really* disturbing me!)

Comment: I believe you can vote on comments on locked posts; there's an open request to [disallow it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/disallow-voting-on-comments-if-a-post-is-locked)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Try it, but *I can't*. I don't think the request you linked is still up to date (19 Jul 2009).

Comment: I did try it on a 2.0 site and it worked fine. Where's the post you're testing on?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Hmm. It failed for me too, but I had other people test it on [Meta Unix and Linux](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/) and it worked, so it's something else about that post or there's a difference between sites

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I tried on other locked posts on SO, same results. Are you sure your people tested it on **locked** posts, and not **closed** questions?

Comment: Ah, never mind. They thought it worked because the arrow lit up, but it didn't actually save, like you reported. I assume it worked for me because I'm a mod there, although normally mods can't bypass locks (e.g. I can't vote on the locked post directly). That's really odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy, the actual error message (already being sent to the browser) will actually be presented now (and the UI resetting as if no vote occurred, like you'd expect).  It'll look like this:

[image: comment error]

Comment: Why not just remove the button altogether?