# Upvoting comments in locked posts

Tags: bug, comment-voting, locked, locked-answers

When a post is locked, you should not be able to vote on it, including comments. But you can vote on comments, until you get stopped by an error.

> [image]

(Found in Jon Skeet Facts).

This should be fixed.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111715/244519

Comment: +1; not a functional problem, but just annoying. The arrows on **historically** locked posts should be hidden.